# CiviGrants - view an extra field

Tags: civigrant

Quick question - How do I get the rationale field to show up under the Grants tab for a contact? Can this be done without access to the "backend code"?

Cheers - Phil

Comment: short answer: no - you would need at least a little bit of code to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no - you would need at least a little bit of code to achieve this.